# How could I dispatch one job from another in Laravel

Tags: laravel, traits, jobs, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

```
Trait method dispatch has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on
```

I'm always getting the above error, now I want to use both Dispatchable and DispatchJobs in a job, how could I do that? Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated. Looked for few solutions on Laracasts but none worked.

Comment: Be careful when dispatching a job within another job! For example: JOB A and JOB B.
When dispatching JOB B within JOB A, whenever something fails within JOB A after JOB B was dispatched, JOB B will be dispatched again when JOB A is being retried!

Answer (score 6):

Use the global `dispatch()` helper and that will work to dispatch another job inside the job. So we don't need to add DispatchesJobs at all (which removes the conflict with Dispatchable) and you can just use the helper `dispatch()` instead and it works

Answer (score 5):

Jobs don't typically dispatch other Jobs, so start by removing the `DispatchJobs` trait. What you can do is listen for [job events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-events).

When a Job completes, it fires the `after` event. Listen for this event and then `dispatch()` the next Job within the listener:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        // determine the job type from $event->job
        // then dispatch the next job based on your logic

        // check the job type
        if ($event->job instanceof MyJob) {
            // get the job payload to pass to next job
            $data = $event->job->payload

            dispatch(new NextJob($data));
            // or use the static method
            NextJob::dispatch($data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @btl, thank you for the reply, I still need your little guidance, now From JOB A, I need to pass some data which is going to be used in JOB B, how could I do that with the after event? And how would I recognise the particular job. I want to fire the event only when JOB A ends. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you so much, but I also found a better solution :), just using global `dispatch();` it doesn't make any conflicts and it works smoothly.

Comment: I've answered my own question, you may take a look :) @btl

Comment: @Siddharth do you have to explicitly set ```\dispatch()``` or simply ```dispatch()``` to make a global call to it?

Comment: @Ulterior simply dispatch()

Answer (score 4):

### This worked for me

inside the `BbtvAdvJob` I dispatch again.

```
 dispatch(new BbtvAdvJob())->delay(3);
```

make sure that you recall `php artisan queue:work` when you change the code of the Job.

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel >=5.3

If your job class is MyAnotherJob, try dispatching

`MyAnotherJob::dispatch()`

Every `Job` class has a static `dispatch` function.
You can use that.

Comment: Guess depends on Laravel version, it's not present in 5.2

Comment: @RZ87 Thanks for finding that out.